# Incorrect Location updates with wifi/mobile network but not with GPS

Tags: android, gps, location, android-wifi

Following is the coding i got from some one else work. I am trying to implement bit of his work with necessary changes in my app. The problem here is that it is not returning the proper address when the GET ADDRESS button is clicked. Besides, it works only with the wifi/mobile network but not with the GPS. Meanwhile, i wonder how to make auto-posting of data to sever when the call is making to a contact. Thank you!

```
package com.yang.address;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddressActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Double lat, lon;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) AddressActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                // Define a listener that responds to location updates
                LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                        lat = location.getLatitude();
                        lon = location.getLongitude();
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoc);
                        tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                };
                // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        });

        Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postData(lat, lon);
            }
        });

        Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddress);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
                tv.setText(GetAddress(lat, lon));
            }
        });

    }

    public void postData(Double lat2, Double lon2) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("http://myappurl.com/Home/Book/"+lat2+"/"+lon2);

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);
            String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", 5000).show();
        }
    } 
    public String GetAddress(Double lat2, Double lon2)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        String ret = "";
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat2,lon2, 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "Can't get Address!";
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've made some progress since your last question.

First off, the `LocationManager` system on androids is Listening Service in that you register it as a listener and allow the OS to notify when updates are made. This means you should have the code you put in your `OnClick` method run *before* you need it. Your best option is to have the `OnCreate` method of your Activity register the listener as the Activity starts and use the `onLocationChanged` callback as a way to store the new `Location` on a class variable.

```
private Location lastKnownLocation;
private TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //....
  setupLocationServices();
  //....
  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoc);
  Button btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
  btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      updateLocation();
    }
  });
  //....
}

private void setupLocationServices() {
  //....
  LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
    lastKnownLocation = location;
    updateLocation();
  }
  ....
}

private void updateLocation() {
  double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
  double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
  tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
}
```

As for your reasoning as to why it doesn't work with GPS it is because you never register the GPS listener. Where you have this line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You would need to substitude in this value:

```
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
```

Again, as I recommended before I really suggest taking the time to fully understand the [Android Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

As for your other problem regarding listening to the state of incoming calls you should start off by checking the `TelephonyManager` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html). Specifically look for the use of `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` and its extras for incoming calls. For outgoing calls google the use of `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` Intents.

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-detail explanation and response. I really appreciate everything. Yes, i read the one you suggested but i will again. I am able to get my outgoing call number with certain receiver class.

Comment: I was thinking about the possibilities of getting and displaying incoming caller location. I thought about sending outgoing number and location to a server where it pushes the location to the call receiver whose number is registered. What do you think? is it right to do?

Comment: I am getting following error with GPS on: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.gideon.address.AddressActivity.GetAddress(AddressActivity.java:109)atcom.gideon.address.AddressActivity$3.onClick(AddressActivity.java:80)